# Second relation to same table returns null

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I've come across a problem with my Eloquent model where having multiple relationships to the same table results in the first working but subsequent relationships return null, despite the data existing.

[image]

The relationship on `created_by` works, however the `completed_by` does not, despite it referencing the same data.

```
public function completed_by_user()
{
    return $this->hasOne('User', 'id', 'completed_by');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne('User', 'id', 'created_by');
}
```

Above are the relationships within my Model of which `$object->user` returns a value, however `$object->completed_by_user` does not.

Am I missing something completely stupid?

Thanks and happy new year :)

Comment: If you change `created_by` to `completed_by` in the `user` relation, does it still work?

Comment: And shouldn't you use `return $this->hasOne('User', 'completed_by')`?

Comment: Changing the `created_by`/`completed_by` and removing `id` didn't help :( - Same issue.

Comment: Wait so does `public function completed_by_user(){ return $this->hasOne('User', 'created_by'); }` work or not? I want to find out why one relation is working and the other isn't...

Comment: That's correct, when changing both to use created_by, the first works but the second doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the name of the relationship from `completed_by_user` to `completedByUser`

The reason behind this is that Laravel converts the dynamic property name to camel case.

So when you try to use `$user->completed_by_user` it searches for the relation function `completedByUser`

Comment: Well spotted! I removed my dodgy `load` work around and changed to the suggested and it worked first time. Thank you! Have a nice new year.

Answer (score 0):

Your relations are wrong, swap the keys:

```
public function completed_by_user()
{
    return $this->hasOne('User', 'completed_by', 'id'); // id may be ommited
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne('User', 'created_by', 'id'); // the same here
}
```

Comment: The `id` should definitely be omitted. This way it will also adapt if the primary key of the `User` class gets changed.

Comment: @lukasgeiter :) true, it will adapt. However it doesn't refer to the `User` class, but the owning model (the one where relation is defined).

Comment: True as well, but I'm pretty sure the owning model is `User` too, since it's a recursive foreign key in the database... ;)

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't helped. Works for the initial `user` relation however the `created_by_user` relation is still null, despite pointing to the same value.

Comment: Well, you had 2 errors there :) Yes, `snake_cased` relations won't work unless eager loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that by calling

```
{{ $question->load('completed_by_user') }}
```

that it started working correctly...